# How do I set up a Navigation Property when the index and the foreign key are different data types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Currently on EF Core 6 at the moment. If it's important, I am using a MySql database.

I have a couple of database models that were auto-generated based on an existing legacy database currently in a production environment. My task is to import this data from the legacy database into a new database schema. Because this is in production, I do NOT have the ability to modify the schema of the database for the sake of what I am about to ask.

This database has related tables. We'll call them Widget and WidgetBlocker. Widget has a primary key of type uint and a many-to-many relationship with WidgetBlocker. WidgetBlocker has a foreign key back to Widget, but the data type (for a reason I do not know) is nullable int. This means that my classes look something like this...

```
public class Widget
{
   public uint WidgetId { get; set; }
.
.
.
}

public class WidgetBlocker
{
   public uint WidgetBlockerId { get; set; }
   public int? WidgetId { get; set; }
.
.
.

}
```

I would like to add a navigation property to Widget like this:

```
public ICollection<WidgetBlocker> Blockers { get; set; }
```

I would then set up the DbContext OnModelCreating like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Widget>(entity =>
{
   entity.HasMany(widget => widget.Blockers).WithMany().HasForeignKey(widgetBlocker => widgetBlocker.WidgetId);
});
```

The code builds just fine, but I get a runtime error stating:

> The relationship...with foreign key property int? cannot target the primary key uint? because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.

Is there a way to follow those instructions (configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types) without modifying the schema of the tables? If not, is there a way to set up the navigation property? Perhaps via an attribute on the class that allows the database to have one data type while the data model has another? Or am I possibly doing something incorrectly beyond the data types issue?

Comment: Why can't you make their types match (C# classes)? What are actual column types in the database? Do you have a foreign key set up in the database?

Comment: To my knowledge, and please correct me if I am wrong, if I change the data type in C#, that necessitates creating a Migration and, subsequently, a modification to the schema. I am not permitted to do that.  

The data types are "int (10) unsigned" for Widget, and "int (11) Nullable" in the foreign key for WidgetBlocker.  

Sadly, the database designer was a beginner back when this was put together originally (mid-90's). There are very few constraints that would be appropriate, and no DB-side foreign keys.

Comment: Do you have a test copy of the database? Try creating the corresponding FK on it. Will it work?

Comment: Also note that you have one-to-many, not many-to-many relationship based on your code, so it should be  `HasMany().WithOne()`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, @GuruStron. Unfortunately, it appears that the table, itself, does not actually support foreign keys. Must have been a very old version of MySQL. Table type is "MyISAM"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> data types are "int (10) unsigned" for Widget, and "int (11) Nullable"

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) on foreign keys (emphasis mine):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar data types. *The size **and sign** of fixed precision types such as INTEGER and DECIMAL **must be the same***. The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.

This means that you can't define a FK on such two columns in general, let alone with EF. Note that your code (if it would worked) should have created a FK which is a scheme modification.

You need to adjust types in the database (code first or database first, depends on your situation and goals) only then you will be able to add this relationship.

Until then you are bound to manual joins and/or other workarounds (views, etc.)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you for your time!